# восстановить незакоммиченные данные из git

Tags: git

Случайно удалил с помощью git reset HEAD~1 --hard коммит, и потом решил его восстановить с помощью
$ git reflog
выбрал нужный коммит
1a75c1d... HEAD@{0}: reset --hard HEAD^: updating HEAD
f6e5064... HEAD@{1}: commit: added file2

$ git reset --hard f6e5064
Коммит восстановил. Но с этими манипуляциями исчезли несколько файлов из папки, которые я не коммитил никуда. Можно ли их как-то восстановить? Читал про кеш редактора, но не пойму как его проверить

Comment: git вряд ли Вам теперь поможет в этом. Но если редактор, которым Вы пользуетесь, держит копии файлов, то можно восстановить, но к git это уже не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: через pycharm работаю

Comment: Если в Pycharm, то смотрите в меню VCS - Local History, возможно там изменения незакоммиченых файлов остались.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае ничего не поможет, сам столкнулся с такой проблемой на пайчарме сегодня